# How can i aggregate tweets into local database with twitter public streams API?

Tags: twitter, stream

I want to collect lots of tweets into local database for my research. I dont want to use Search API cause it is for the past tweets. I may need some programs runing for 3 months to collect sufficient tweets. Is there any way i can do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use streaming api and collect live tweets.
[Public Stream](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-apis/streams/public) can help you too!